# Get current page query string parameters in apex

Tags: apex

How does one to get query string parameters with apex in a controller and eventually into a visualforce page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would be a clean way to do it:

```
apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get();

// For URL - http://test.salesforce.com/apex/helloworld?q=texas


//use the following
String queryString ='';
queryString = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('q');
```

[Source](http://www.oyecode.com/2013/08/how-to-read-page-parameters-quickly.html)

Comment: How can this answer get 12 upvotes? I wish there was a more full fledged example than this. What is written in Apex and example of it called in VF page?

Answer (score 7):

Parameters passed to the page through URL can be accessed in controller using below syntax,

```
String parameterValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('parameterName');
```

Usually it is used in constructor of controller to get value and then do operations based on the parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Apex provides methods to get the current URL parameters.

The salesforce documentation [PageReference class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm) has information regarding getting the page instance and then getting query string parameters.

**Example from the Salesforce documentation:**

```
public class MyController {
   public Account getAccount() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
                WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];
    }
}
```

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Retrieving Query String Parameters">
        You are viewing the {!account.name} account.
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is a horrible example. You should not be querying records directly in a getter, nor should you ordinarily be grabbing the ID value from a query string; instead, you should be using the standardController attribute and allow Visualforce to query the account on your behalf.

Comment: @sfdcfox  , I copied this from the [salesforce documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm). Sorry i'm new. I guess this example is a bit niave. Could you possibly help me with a better example?