# Use Command Button to set Controller Variable

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two visualforce pages and one class.

At the **first page (calc)** I have just Information about some Company Details and a command button which connect to a **second page (calc_test)**. At the second page you can calculate a bit.

I wanna set the variable **calc_view to 1** if I click at the button. Below you will find my code, but it doesn't work.

I think the value get lost if I click the button, but why?
I tried also with action argument and an additional method of:

```
public PageReference calc_click() {
    calc_view = 1;
    return new PageReference('/apex/calc_test');
}
```

but it doesnt work.

**Visualforce Page: calc**

```
<apex:commandButton value="CALC" onclick="window.open('/apex/calc_test','_blank','height=500,width=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizeable=no,menubar=no,top=200,left=200'); return false;">
    <apex:param name="TEST" value="1" assignTo="{!calc_view}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

**Visualforce Page: calc_test**

```
<apex:page controller="calc_class" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!If(calc_VIEW=1,true,false)}">   
<apex:inputText value="{!value1}" maxlength="10" style="width:40px"/>
    <br/>
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, #,##0}"><apex:param value="{!value2}"/></apex:outputText>
    <br/>
<apex:commandbutton value="calc" action="{!Pr_calc}" />

</apex:outputPanel>      
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Class: calc_class**

```
public class calc_class {

    public Integer calc_VIEW {get; set;}

    public Double value1 {get; set;}
    public Double value2 {get; set;}

    public calc_class() {
        calc_VIEW = 0;
    }

    public PageReference Pr_calc() {
        value2= value1/ 3.35 * 100;
        return new PageReference('/apex/calc_test');   
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try passing the value as a query parameter to second page?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the data across the controllers, you have to use [setRedirect(redirect)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm).

As per documentation:

> If setRedirect(false), the redirect is a server-side forward that
>   preserves the view state if and only if the target page uses the same
>   controller and contains the proper subset of extensions used by the
>   source page.

Try changing the code to:

```
public PageReference calc_click() {
    calc_view = 1;
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/calc_test');
    pr.setRedirect(false);
    return pr;
}
```

Other option would be to use send data to next page as a [query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69808/get-current-page-query-string-parameters-in-apex) parameter.